# Phase issue with web audio API convolver node

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

I have made an online synth and it has a reverb effect using the web audio API convolver node, and I would say around 10% of the time you open up the synth the convolver node has some audible phase issues, as though the left and right are slightly out of phase.

```
let reverb = context.createConvolver();
let reverbGain = context.createGain();
reverbGain.gain.value = 2;
delayFeedback.connect(reverbGain);
reverbGain.connect(reverb);
let anotherReverbGain = context.createGain();
anotherReverbGain.gain.value = 0;
reverbIn.connect(anotherReverbGain);
let takeOutLow = context.createBiquadFilter();
takeOutLow.type = 'lowshelf';
takeOutLow.frequency.value = 400;
takeOutLow.gain.value = -10;
anotherReverbGain.connect(takeOutLow);
takeOutLow.connect(reverb);

let loadImpulse = function ()
{
let url = "audio/impulse.wav";
let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open( "GET", url, true );
request.responseType = "arraybuffer";
request.onload = function (){
    context.decodeAudioData( request.response, function ( buffer ) {
        reverb.buffer = buffer;
    });
}
request.send();
};

loadImpulse();
```

Comment: Can you make this a jsfiddle or codepen or whatever that includes the impulse response?  Your sample code also seems incomplete: you use `reverbIn`, but don't define it any where.

Comment: Yeah I could, however the reverbIn is essentially an entire synth. http://www.disco-computer.com/synthesizer/synth.html

Comment: Ok. If you think it's a bug in the browser, file a bug against your browser  Although it's unlikely any one is going to happy to debug the full app.

Comment: OK I worked this out in the end. I had fed back my delay (to get it repeating) but also  had a feedback loop on my reverb for some reason, causing the phase issue.